# Symfony2 / prod : css & javascript filename not generated

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

After moving my symfony2 app to production, my homepage and and links related to the frontend part work fine (domain.com/event/xxxx, domain.com/category/yyy etc). CSS & JS are correctly loaded.
However, my admin part which is accessible via domain.com/admin is not. When I check out the generated html, I find my CSS & JS filenames are null.

I am getting something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/.css"> 
<script src="/js/.js"></script>
```

I have cleared cache and dumped assetic :

```
./console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
./console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

but nothing happens, the problem persists.

BTW, clearing the prod cache displays weird lines that do not show I clear the dev cache, I get some output like this :

```
Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false Mac OS X           2??ATTR?????j?
                                  com.apple.TextEncoding?_de.codingmonkeys.seestatemacintosh;0d1:pd1:yi85e1:wi1572e1:xi32e1:hi922ee1:sd1:pi1245e1:li0ee1:ei1e1:li1919e1:m16:SEEMode.PHP-HTMLeThis resource fork intentionally left blank   ??Mac O
```

If you need to see my config files, just tell me which files you need and I will paste them.

Any help please ?

**EDIT**

ok I don't know if this is correct or not, but I found this [Assetic not creating combined links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261562/assetic-not-creating-combined-links)

and after changing 
    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

by (the opposite of what is described in that link), it is working.
    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

Can I keep it like that ?

Comment: The second parameter of the `AppKernel` class defines the `$debug` option. You should not use it in production.

Comment: if I turn it on (= true) I get empty filenames, as I described

Comment: Well, generally, it should be set to false for prod so you're all good.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
app/console cache:warmup --env=prod
app/console assets:install --symlink
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

These commands helped me when the CSS was not loading. I always like to clear my caches whenever doing stuff like this. `app/console assetic:dump --env=prod` I think is the command that makes this work since it is the one that [compiles the CSS and JS into one file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment).

Comment: Check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html .  You probably want to add `--no-debug` to your `cache:clear` and `assetic:dump calls`