# Assetic bad css files link in prod env

Tags: css, symfony, http-status-code-404, production, assetic

I'm trying to test my application in a production environment context. The problem is that Assetic is not working properly.

the css files and js files are not loaded.

Here's what I did:

- I was setted : `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`
- I excecuted the commands:

  php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
  php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug

so far, no problems, my files have been created:

```
01:07:26 [file+] /var/www/visual-immersion/app/../web/js/b0c2086.js
01:07:26 [file+] /var/www/visual-immersion/app/../web/js/a49caf1.js
01:07:26 [file+] /var/www/visual-immersion/app/../web/css/a580ac9.css
```

But when i launch my web page, no css, no js. if i inspect my source code page, i can see:

```
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="/css/a580ac9_part_1_home_1.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9_layout_2.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9_style_3.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9_font_4.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9_responsive_5.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9_animations_6.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9_personalized-responsive_7.css">
```

as if i was in dev env !

So i cleaned my cache in dev env too, and restarted my process to prod env...No success.

Do you know what is problem ?

i add my config.yml :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [VisualImmersionAdminBundle, VisualImmersionSiteBundle]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
        transport: gmail
        username:  contact@visual-immersion.com
        password:  mypassword
```

Edit:

I retried the procedure with assets: install without success.

Edit 2:

in my web browser dev tool, if i add the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/a580ac9.css">
```

It is work. I really think Assetic load files as dev env  instead of prod env.
Any idea?

EDIT 3:

I add the layout or managed css files, if it can help ...

```
{% stylesheets '@VisualImmersionSiteBundle/Resources/public/css/*'  filter='cssrewrite'
            'css/stylesheets/layout.css'
            'css/stylesheets/style.css'
            'css/stylesheets/font.css'
            'css/stylesheets/responsive.css'
            'css/stylesheets/animations.css'
            'css/stylesheets/personalized-responsive.css'
        %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">

        {% endstylesheets %}
```

EDIT 4:

i tried to change my stylesheets filter like this:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
        'css/stylesheets/*'
        'bundles/visualimmersionsite/css/*'
    %}
```

but no success.

Comment: I wonder if the use_controller: false works in the config.yml. Because if I understand, Assetic still trying to dynamically load files, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled on it by accident:

[Assetic not creating combined links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261562/assetic-not-creating-combined-links)

And it actually works. I do not understand anything. For the prod work, you must set 'prod' to false.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

This way, instead of having a copy of each bundle's resources, you'll have a symlink, so there should be no need to update.

From docs:

> When using the cssrewrite filter, don't refer to your CSS files using
>   the @AcmeFooBundle syntax.

Try this way:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/acme_foo/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I forgot to say, but I did too. Moreover, the images are present. Only js and css files are missing. What's really weird is that it display for files that should be generated in dev mode rather than in prod.

Comment: Maybe browser cache? Have you checked for that?

Comment: Maybe i forget to set a param to pass in prod, in my config.yml, app.php or another else ? Do you see something of anormal ?

Comment: I tested your delete solution of annotation for css, but not better. Also note that files that are directly in web are concerned too.

Answer (score 1):

Setting prod to false is not what's happening.

You're setting the environment to prod and debug to false:

```
class Kernel ...

public function __construct($environment, $debug)
```