# 404. The routing does not work, but the landing page is working. Styles files are not loaded. Symfony

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, deployment

I apologize for my bad english. Please help me.
I deploy site by ftp on host Reg.ru. I performed all the operations that I recommend [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html) using the console on ssh.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('homepage/index.html.twig');
}
```

Link on a file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/homepage/main.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('js/slider/style.css') }}" />
```

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: [My site](http://www.boldast.ru)

Comment: You dump assets (like `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`)?

Comment: Yes! 1. php bin/console assets:install
2. php bin/console assetic:dump
3. php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
4. php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The documentRoot was not setted up corectly.
It should have point to the /web directory.

Comment: Hey. It did not help. I'm contain css and js in / web.

Comment: symfony not see web directory

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261562/assetic-not-creating-combined-links

Comment: it did not help((

Comment: Can you give me info about your Virtual Hosts configuration?If you put web  in the path the files are visible, but the app should serve the files from that directory without putting it there manually. So I suppose is a configuration problem in the combination of the virtual hosts and .htaccess.

Comment: where i can see this configuration?

Comment: Should be in the apache configuration folder, in httpd.conf

Comment: If you don't have access to it , maybe you have access to a cpanel? You should check over there the DocumentRoot. It should point to the web folder from your app

Comment: That's what gives me tech support when I request this file `<Directory /var/www/u0225224/data/www/boldast.ru>
        ServerName boldast.ru
        CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/boldast.ru.access.log combined
        DocumentRoot /var/www/u0225224/data/www/boldast.ru
        ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/boldast.ru.error.log
        ServerAdmin webmaster@boldast.ru
        ServerAlias www.boldast.ru
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/u0225224/data/www/boldast.ru/cgi-bin/`
What do I need to correct? Add / web to DocumentRoot?

Comment: yes, you should add to DocumentRoot /web normally. In boldast.ru folder you have your app right?

Comment: So you should have in.htaccess: <Directory /var/www/u0225224/data/www/boldast.ru/web> 
and DocumentRoot /var/www/u0225224/data/www/boldast.ru/web

Comment: I did add /web to DocumentRoot and site do working. Thank you very much! I am happy.

Comment: I'm glad. Good luck with the next features!